# How to extract video urls and titles from OK.ru/video using the CLI

Tags: json, css-selectors, jq, pup

EDIT 1:
I'd like to extract video urls and titles from "https://ok.ru/video/c1404844" results using the CLI.

Here's want I've done so far :

The ERE pattern for each video relative URL is :
`/video/\d+` and the video absolute URL looks like this : `https://ok.ru$videoRelativeURL`

I can use this command to extract the video urls (I use `uniq` because many video IDs appear 3 times) :

```bash
$ curl -s https://ok.ru/video/c1404844 | grep -oP "/video/\d+" | uniq | sed "s|^|https://ok.ru|" | head -5
https://ok.ru/video/1896971373228
https://ok.ru/video/1896971438764
https://ok.ru/video/1896971569836
https://ok.ru/video/1896971635372
https://ok.ru/video/1898415590060
```

Then I tried extracting the video relativeURLs + title with [pup](https://github.com/EricChiang/pup).

EDIT 3 : I replaced the class name `video-card_n ellip` by `video-card_n.ellip`. However `pup` only outputs the attribute of the second class (`video-card_n.ellip`), strange :

```bash
$ curl -s https://ok.ru/video/c1404844 | pup '.video-card_lk attr{href}, .video-card_n.ellip attr{title}' | head -5
Death.in.Paradise.S02E05.WEBRip.x264-ION10
Death.in.Paradise.S02E02.WEBRip.x264-ION10
Death.in.Paradise.S02E04.WEBRip.x264-ION10
Death.in.Paradise.S02E03.WEBRip.x264-ION10
Death.in.Paradise.S02E06.WEBRip.x264-ION10
```

It didn't work so I converted the expanded html to json with this command :

```bash
$ curl -s https://ok.ru/video/c1404844 | pup 'json{}' > c1404844.json
```

Now I want to try and extract the `title` from `video-card_n ellip` and the `href` from `video-card_lk` from the resulting json file with the [jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq) tool but I know how to use `jq` enough.

I'd like `jq` (or `pup`) to output a flat file : the url as the first column and the title as the second column.

EDIT 2 : A big thank you to @peak for his help on `jq` !

DONE :

```bash
$ curl -s https://ok.ru/video/c1404844 | pup 'json{}' | jq -r 'recurse | arrays[] | select(.class == "video-card_lk").href,select(.class == "video-card_n ellip").title' | awk '{videoRelativeURL = $0;url="https://ok.ru"gensub("?.*$","",videoRelativeURL); getline title; print url" # "title}' | head
https://ok.ru/video/1898417425068 # Death.in.Paradise.S02E05.WEBRip.x264-ION10
https://ok.ru/video/1898417359532 # Death.in.Paradise.S02E02.WEBRip.x264-ION10
https://ok.ru/video/1898417293996 # Death.in.Paradise.S02E04.WEBRip.x264-ION10
https://ok.ru/video/1898417228460 # Death.in.Paradise.S02E03.WEBRip.x264-ION10
https://ok.ru/video/1898417162924 # Death.in.Paradise.S02E06.WEBRip.x264-ION10
https://ok.ru/video/1898417097388 # Death.in.Paradise.S02E07.WEBRip.x264-ION10
https://ok.ru/video/1898417031852 # Death.in.Paradise.S02E08.WEBRip.x264-ION10
https://ok.ru/video/1898416966316 # Death.in.Paradise.S02E01.WEBRip.x264-ION10
https://ok.ru/video/1898416769708 # Death.in.Paradise.S07E02.The.Stakes.Are.High.WEBRip.x264-ION10
https://ok.ru/video/1898416704172 # Death.in.Paradise.S07E03.Written.in.Murder.WEBRip.x264-ION10
...
```

Comment: It may be possible to answer the `jq` portion of your question if you provide a short sample of `my_results__expanded_HTML.json` file. See [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for guidance.

Comment: It seems that neither pup nor xidel supports spaces in class name selectors :-(

Comment: @peak `pup` does if you replace spaces in class names by `.`

Comment: @jq170727 I do unsterstand but the file is too big (~ 12M), do you how I can share it ?

Comment: @SebMa - I think you're basically making my point, but a character such as _ that does not have special significance in pup might be better.

Comment: @jq170727 Please see my EDIT 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to scrape specific information from a HTML-source, then there's no need for 5 different tools! Please have a look at [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel). It can do it all.

```sh
$ xidel -s https://ok.ru/video/c1404844 -e '
  //div[@data-id]/join(
    (
      div[@class="video-card_img-w"]/a/resolve-uri(substring-before(@href,"?")),
      div[@class="video-card_n-w"]/a
    ),
    " # "
  )
'
https://ok.ru/video/1898417425068 # Death.in.Paradise.S02E05.WEBRip.x264-ION10
https://ok.ru/video/1898417359532 # Death.in.Paradise.S02E02.WEBRip.x264-ION10
https://ok.ru/video/1898417293996 # Death.in.Paradise.S02E04.WEBRip.x264-ION10
https://ok.ru/video/1898417228460 # Death.in.Paradise.S02E03.WEBRip.x264-ION10
https://ok.ru/video/1898417162924 # Death.in.Paradise.S02E06.WEBRip.x264-ION10
https://ok.ru/video/1898417097388 # Death.in.Paradise.S02E07.WEBRip.x264-ION10
https://ok.ru/video/1898417031852 # Death.in.Paradise.S02E08.WEBRip.x264-ION10
https://ok.ru/video/1898416966316 # Death.in.Paradise.S02E01.WEBRip.x264-ION10
https://ok.ru/video/1898416769708 # Death.in.Paradise.S07E02.The.Stakes.Are.High.WEBRip.x264-ION10
https://ok.ru/video/1898416704172 # Death.in.Paradise.S07E03.Written.in.Murder.WEBRip.x264-ION10
[...]
```

Comment: Congratulations, can you please add the url to `xidel` source code ?

Comment: @SebMa Just click the `xidel`-tag and then "Learn more…".

Comment: Thanks for your [xidel](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xidel/info) link.

Answer (score 1):

After using [pup](/questions/tagged/pup) to convert the HTML of the top-level page to JSON, the following jq filter produces 24 pairs, the first two of which are shown under "Output" below:

```
[ [ .. | arrays[] | select(.class == "video-card_n ellip").title],
  [ .. | arrays[] | select(.class == "video-card_lk").href]]
| transpose
```

#### Output

```
[
  [
    "Замечательная пара, красивая песня и чудесное исполнение! Золотые голоса!",
    "/video/2406311403450?st._aid=VideoState_open_top"
  ],
  [
    "#СидимДома",
    "/video/1675421949619?st._aid=VideoState_open_top"
  ],
  ...
```

Comment: If you download the html file after scrolling down to the bottom of the results and save the expanded html with [Save Page WE](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-page-we/dhhpefjklgkmgeafimnjhojgjamoafof), you should obtain 585 pairs

Comment: Can you explain what is the meaning of `.. | arrays[]` ?

Comment: @SebMa - Please check the jq manual.  Also, the page scrolls indefinitely.  It might be better to post a sample or synopsis of the HTML you think is typical.

Comment: The `array` word is all over the place in the [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/). And I couldn't find this `arrays[]` notation in the [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) so I tried to replace `arrays[]` by `dummy[]` to test if `arrays` was a keyword or a variable name. I'm lost here, can you help ?

Comment: `arrays` appears in the title of a subsection describing the builtins: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Builtinoperatorsandfunctions.  You can use `builtins` to view the built-in functions. `arrays[]` is equivalent to `arrays | .[]`

Comment: And `.. | arrays[]` is equivalent to `recurse(arrays[])` ?

Comment: No. .. is equivalent to recurse (i.e. recurse/0). You can check the defs of builtins such as `arrays` by viewing builtin.jq